# Squid site redirection

Tags: proxy, squid, rewrite

I have an internal  website that cannot be accessed from some machines on my network, due to the physical location, VPN ,network ranges etc. I would like to install Squid on "in between" network to forward request from the clients that cannot reach the website.

The issue is the clients have no ability to connect to www.example.com , but they can reach a  network with a squid proxy , which in turn can reach www.example.com

What is the correct term  I need to research in squid , is it just caching www.example.com or do I need to set the clients to use a URL that gets rewritten ?  i.e www.squid-example.com  -- > www.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. One would be:

Configure Squid as a "normal" forwading (caching is fine) proxy. This usually the default configuration.
Change the http_access settings in the squid.conf, so that only www.example.com can be accessed through this proxy. Otherwise this proxy can be used to bypass security restrictions in your network.
Write (or extend the existing) proxy.pac for your web browsers, to use this proxy to reach www.example.com and tell your web browsers to use it.

Comment: I'm wondering if DNS wouldn't be more easy to use to redirect?

Comment: If the server is not directly reachable for the clients, DNS alone won't do it.

Comment: well, true indeed. Squid is still the best solution.

http://server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=squid <<< this might help you AndyM, installing your squid, and creating the proxy.pac.